# How to change all cell's height and width in laravel excel

Tags: php, laravel

**I want to apply height and width for all row's in laravel excel**

I am able to change height and width for single row at time by using following code

```
 $sheet->setSize('A1', 25, 18);
 $sheet->setSize('B1', 25, 18);
 $sheet->setSize('C1', 25, 18);
 $sheet->setSize('D1', 25, 18);
 $sheet->setSize('E1', 25, 18);
 $sheet->setSize('F1', 25, 18);
```

**Now question is I have thousands of rows so How I can manage that ?**

I have following code

```
 \Excel::create('Users Report'.$time, function ($excel) use ($arrUsers) {


            $excel->sheet('Users', function ($sheet) use ($arrUsers) {

                // Set all margins
                $sheet->fromArray($arrUsers, null, 'A1', true);

                $sheet->setSize('A1', 25, 18);
                $sheet->setSize('B1', 25, 18);
                $sheet->setSize('C1', 25, 18);
                $sheet->setSize('D1', 25, 18);
                $sheet->setSize('E1', 25, 18);
                $sheet->setSize('F1', 25, 18);

                $sheet->row(1, array(
                    'Name', 'Username', 'Contact', 'Email', 'Verified', 'Inactivity'
                ));

                // Freeze first row
                $sheet->freezeFirstRow();

                $sheet->cell('A1:F1', function($cell) {

                    // Set font
                    $cell->setFont(array(
                        'family'     => 'Calibri',
                        'size'       => '12',
                        'bold'       =>  true
                    ));

                });

            });
        })->store('xls')->download('xls');
```

Please help me out from this stuck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solve this by using the following code

```
 \Excel::create('Users Report'.$time, function ($excel) use ($arrUsers) {


            $excel->sheet('Users', function ($sheet) use ($arrUsers) {

                // Set all margins
                $sheet->fromArray($arrUsers, null, 'A1', true);

                for( $intRowNumber = 1; $intRowNumber <= count($arrUsers) + 1; $intRowNumber++){
                    $sheet->setSize('A' . $intRowNumber, 25, 18);
                    $sheet->setSize('B' . $intRowNumber, 25, 18);
                    $sheet->setSize('C' . $intRowNumber, 25, 18);
                    $sheet->setSize('D' . $intRowNumber, 25, 18);
                    $sheet->setSize('E' . $intRowNumber, 25, 18);
                    $sheet->setSize('F' . $intRowNumber, 25, 18);
                }

                $sheet->row(1, array(
                    'Name', 'Username', 'Contact', 'Email', 'Verified', 'Inactivity'
                ));

                // Freeze first row
                $sheet->freezeFirstRow();

                $sheet->cell('A1:F1', function($cell) {

                    // Set font
                    $cell->setFont(array(
                        'family'     => 'Calibri',
                        'size'       => '12',
                        'bold'       =>  true
                    ));

                });

            });
        })->store('xls')->download('xls');
```

Comment: How to do this in version 3.x?

Answer (score 1):

For version 3.* you can use `WithEvents` concern:

```
AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {
   // row height                  
   $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getRowDimension('2')->setRowHeight(40);
}
```